# Oracle- How to append values inside a loop and access it outside loop?

Tags: oracle, loops, cursor

My cursor records will be like this

| Queue | steps |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | R |

> ```
> Loop
>   Fetch cusor1 into rec1
>   Exit when cursor1%not found
>   strval := 'val =' || rec1.queue||' '||rec1.steps;
> End loop;
> ```

The output I am expecting is

`Val = 1A 2B 3C 4D 5R`

Answer (score 1):

Skip the cursor and use `LISTAGG`:

```sql
DECLARE
  strval VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'Val = ' || LISTAGG(queue || steps, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY queue)
  INTO   strval
  FROM   table_name;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(strval);
END;
/
```

If you must use a cursor then:

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR cursor1 IS
    SELECT queue, steps
    FROM   table_name
    ORDER BY queue;

  strval  VARCHAR2(4000) := 'Val =';
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN cursor1 LOOP
    strval := strval || ' ' || rec.queue|| rec.steps;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(strval);
END;
/
```

Which both output:

> ```
> Val = 1A 2B 3C 4D 5E
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b0632ec30115e929d55bbd00c8c803e2)*

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```
Loop 
Fetch cusor1 into rec1 
  Exit when cursor1%not found 
  strval := concat(strval, rec1.queue||''||rec1.steps || ' '); 
End 
loop;

strval := concat('val =', strval)
```